# How to install games directly to SD card without going through phone or internal memory

Tags: external-sd, installation, insufficient-memory

I have a [Micromax Canvas A177](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/micromax-a177-canvas-juice-1353) Android device which has 4GB of storage and 1GB of RAM.  Currently, I only have 700 MB of storage available and I cannot install any more applications.

I have a SD card installed in the device, but to move an application to the SD card, I first have to install it in the phone storage, which I cannot due because of limited space.

How can I install an app directly to external storage without first having to install it in phone storage?

Comment: Go through the one time steps mentioned [on this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/114667/how-to-install-android-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-move-almost-any-app-to-the-sd-card/).